# Question about printing half triangle with numbers

Tags: c#

[image: Error message]

I get this error message and i dont know whats wrong with it. The code doesnt have to be done with for

```
    using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    
            int i, j;
 
            for(i=1;i<9;i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<= i;j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("" + j);
                }   
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Think you might need to write to them and say "Error: your website does not operate correctly" :) but ..

Comment: ..perhaps it's a new line issue. Maybe the site is expecting \r\n and your code is printing \n or vice versa. Change that WriteLine to `Write("\r\n")` or `Write("\n")`..

Comment: ps; fwiw I would put the int i,j into the loop spec like `for(int i...` and you don't need to `""+`

Comment: @CaiusJard I'd also try `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string current = string.Empty;
 
        for(int i=1;i<9;i++)
        {
            current += i.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(current);
        }
    }
}
```

You dont need to declare "int i;" just declare it in the for loop.
You dont need the j loop as you are only adding the latest number to the output.

Comment: Don't need the .ToString either